# The formal proof that one Turing Machine recognizes one specific language

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, proof-techniques

When given one *grammar*, we can formally prove that it can recognize one language using [QA_1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11316/161388)

Since [Kleene's Theorem](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Etoida/nerzic/390teched/regular/fa/kleene-2.html) gives the equivalence between the regular grammar and the NFA, we can also use QA_1 to prove that one NFA can recognize one language by *transfroming the NFA to the grammar* firstly.

Then how to prove that one Turing Machine recognizes one specific language? This [QA_2 answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/503935/1059606) uses contradiction to prove. But it seems *informal* for me.

---

Take $\{0^n 1^n:n\ge 1\}$ for example. I followed [this lecture](https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2015/winter/28000-1/Lec13.pdf).

Since there is no non-terminal/terminal symbols for the Turing Machine, it seems inconvenient to construct $M_i$ when following QA_1.

So I followed [QA_3 answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/110858/161388). It is trivial to prove the Turing Machine in p4 of the above lecture can accept $\{0^n 1^n:n\ge 1\}$, but how to prove that it *can't accept others*?

Both the reference QA_3 answer and [QA_4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1367655/1059606) answer gives one strategy to construct states, but they didn't give one formal proof.

Q:

How to prove the Turing Machine in the above reference lecture recognizes $\{0^n 1^n:n\ge 1\}$? Is it impossible to give one formal proof since [the halting problem is an unsolvable decision problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643850/is-there-a-way-to-prove-that-a-turing-machine-computes-the-function-we-designed#comment3352654_1643850)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The halting problem doesn't really tell you anything about whether you can prove that a TM recognises a given language.

We can prove that the TM recognises $\{0^n1^m : n \geq 1\}$ using the definition of $L(M)$ and $\mapsto_M$.
One thing to note is that the machine is *deterministic*, so for each state and character there's at most one transition.
Therefore for each input $w$ there's only one sequence of IDs (one *computation*) we need to consider to decide if $w \in L(M)$.

These proofs can get very long since there are a lot of cases to consider, so I'll just give a rough sketch.

---

For simplicity we'll write $\mapsto$ instead of $\mapsto_M$, note the following:

> Lemma 1: $X^kq_00^nY^k1^m \mapsto^* X^{k + 1}q_00^{n - 1}Y^{k + 1}1^{m - 1}$ for $k, n, m \in \mathbb{N}; n,m \geq 1$ using only states $q_0, q_1, q_2 \notin F$.

This can be proven by applying the definitions of $\mapsto$ and $M$.
A corollary of Lemma 1 is that for $n \geq m$

$$X^kq_00^nY^k1^m \mapsto^* X^{k + m}q_00^{n - m}Y^{k + m}$$

and for $m \geq n$

$$X^kq_00^nY^k1^m \mapsto^* X^{k + n}q_0Y^{k + n}1^{m - n}$$

using only transitions through $q_0, q_1$ and $q_2$.
From this it follows that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}; n \geq 1$

$$\underbrace{q_00^n1^n}_{=\ X^0q_00^nY^01^n} \mapsto^* X^nq_0Y^n \mapsto X^nYq_3Y^{n - 1} \mapsto^* X^nY^nq_3B \mapsto X^nY^nBq_4B$$

with $q_4 \in F$, so by definition $0^n1^n \in L(M)$.

Now assume that $w \in \Sigma^*; w \notin \{0^n1^n : n \geq 1\}$, then one of the following cases must be true:

- $w = \varepsilon$ or $w = 1x$ for $x \in \Sigma^*$, then $M$ on $w$ directly halts in $q_0 \notin F \Rightarrow w \notin L(M)$.
- $w = 0^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}; n \geq 1$, then
  $$q_0w \mapsto Xq_10^{n - 1} \mapsto^* X0^{n - 1}q_1B$$
  so the machine halts in $q_1$ without ever entering a final state.
  Thus $w \notin L(M)$.
- $w = 0^n1^m$ for $n, m \geq 1; n \neq m$, if $n > m$ then by the corollary of Lemma 1
  $$q_0w \mapsto^* X^mq_00^{n - m}Y^m \mapsto^* X^{m + 1}0^{n - m - 1}Y^mq_1B$$
  so $M$ halts in $q_1$ without having entered a final state.
  If $m > n$ then again by Lemma 1
  $$q_0w \mapsto^* X^nq_0Y^n1^{m - n} \mapsto^* X^nY^nq_31^{m - n}$$
  so $M$ halts in $q_3$ without having entered a final state.
  Thus $w \notin L(M)$.
- $w = 0^n1^m0x$ for $n, m \geq 1$ and $x \in \Sigma^*$, $w \notin L(M)$ can be proven similar to the cases above by considering $n = m$, $n > m$ and $m > n$.

So $w \in \{0^n1^n : n \geq 1\} \iff w \in L(M)$, thus $L(M) = \{0^n1^n : n \geq 1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation. 1. I add some correction of your answer based on my understanding. Hope the correction isn't wrong. 2. For the last case, I proved as the following hinted by your answer. Hope they are right. 2.1 $n=m$ which is similar to $w = 0^n1^m,m>n$: $$q_0w \mapsto^* X^nq_0Y^n0x \mapsto^* X^n Y^n q_30x$$ 2.2 $m>n$ similar to $w = 0^n1^m,m>n$: $$q_0w \mapsto^* X^nq_0Y^n1^{m - n}0x \mapsto^* X^nY^nq_31^{m - n}0x$$

Comment: 2.3 $n>m$ 2.3.1 $1\not\subseteq x$ we have $$q_0w \mapsto^* X^mq_00^{n - m}Y^m0^k \mapsto^* X^{m + 1}0^{n - m - 1}Y^mq_10^k \mapsto^* X^{m + 1}0^{n - m - 1}Y^m 0^kq_1B$$ 2.3.2 $1\subseteq x$ we have $$q_0w \mapsto^* X^mq_00^{n - m}Y^m0x \mapsto^* X^{m + 1}0^{n - m - 1}Y^mq_10x \mapsto^* X^{m + 1}0^{n - m - 1}Y^m 0^{k'} q_1 1 \mapsto^* X^{m + 1}0^{n - m - 1}Y^m 0^{k'-1}q_2 0Y \mapsto^* X^{m + 1}0^{n - m - 1}Y^{m-1} q_2 Y0^{k'}Y$$

Comment: Hi @An5Drama, thanks for taking the time to review my answer.
One thing has me confused though, why would you restrict the lemma to $n \neq m$?
It should hold true either way, but it can't be applied to prove $0^n1^n \in L(M)$ using the addition.

Comment: Re to "why would you restrict the lemma to $n\neq m$": because you says "such that the machine *never enters a final state*". But the machine will enter a final state for $X^kq_00^nY^k1^m,n=m$.

Comment: Oh ok, maybe my phrasing wasn't great there.
What was meant was that *during* the steps from $X^kq_00^nY^k1^m$ to $X^{k + 1}q_00^{n - 1}Y^{k + 1}1^{m - 1}$ it never enters a final state.
It might enter a final state afterwards.

Comment: I've changed the phrasing now (and applied your correction in one of the cases, thanks btw), is this better?

Comment: Thanks. Fine for me.